# Sending Options command to SIP UDP server

Tags: java, udp, sip, datagram, udpclient

I am working on a program which needs to figure out if remote SIP UDP port 5060 is reachable from client machine.

As there is no direct method to check the availability of UDP port. I want to create a simple java class which will send the OPTIONS message to SIP UDP server and then the server will reply back to client in java.

Any help/ direction will be great help!

Thanks,
Anupam

Thanks for your response, I tried below piece of code but it did not get any reply from server:

```
String message = "OPTIONS sip:opensips@host;transport=udp SIP/2.0\r\nCall-ID: 7df5e96c6b1b98af25ad6c7845d48f5d@49.249.132.30\r\nCSeq: 1 OPTIONS\r\nFrom: \"Anupam\" <sip:Anupam@localhost:5080>;tag=textclientv1.0\r\nTo: \"opensips\" <sip:opensips@host>\r\nVia: SIP/2.0/UDP 49.249.132.30:5080;branch=z9hG4bK-3938-f66aaa8dda2fe3b863b4acde5fbcab67\r\nMax-Forwards: 70\r\nContact: \"Anupam\" <sip:Anupam@localhost:5080>\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n";


System.out.println("Message is "+ message);
byte [] data = message.getBytes();
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( data, data.length, host, port ) ;
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To do this by the book (compliant with [RFC 3261](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt)), you will either need to create quite a bit of machinery to handle retransmissions, etc., or to use a library like [JAIN-SIP](http://jsip.java.net/).

However, you may be able to get most of the way there by simply opening a UDP socket, sending a String containing an appropriately-formatted `OPTIONS` message over the socket, and then waiting a while to see if you get a SIP response on that socket. Any old SIP response (success or error) will verify that the server is reachable.

Here is an example `OPTIONS` message from the RFC:

```
OPTIONS sip:carol@chicago.com SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP pc33.atlanta.com;branch=z9hG4bKhjhs8ass877
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:carol@chicago.com>
From: Alice <sip:alice@atlanta.com>;tag=1928301774
Call-ID: a84b4c76e66710
CSeq: 63104 OPTIONS
Contact: <sip:alice@pc33.atlanta.com>
Accept: application/sdp
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried below piece of code but it did not get any reply from server:

Comment: I don't know what code you are referring to. Do you have access to the server to see if it received the message? If not, you can set up another SIP UA and use that for testing your code. (It should reply to the `OPTIONS` message.)

Comment: I can't answer as I am new to this portal. I have edited the main question.

Comment: My suggestion remains the same: set up a SIP UA that you can control and then use your program to send OPTIONS to it and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please help me to understand SIP UA and how can I setup?

Comment: What OS are you using? You can search for one for your preferred platform.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check remote side UDP sip service availability using REGISTER method you can use the following code.

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.Random;

public class CheckSipUdp{
    //Check remote SIP service availability
    public void checkSipUdp(String ipAddress, int outPort)throws Exception{
        DatagramSocket sipSocket = new DatagramSocket(0);
        sipSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);
        InetAddress inetIpAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
        byte [] sendData = new byte[1024];
        byte [] receiveData = new byte[1024];

        //Message/Method which will be used for checking remote server availability.
        String method = "REGISTER sip:" + ipAddress + ":" + outPort + " SIP/2.0\r\nCall-ID: " + generateCallId() + "@" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() +"\r\nCSeq: 1 REGISTER\r\nFrom: <sip:" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + ":" + sipSocket.getLocalPort() + ">;tag=" + new Random().nextInt() + "\r\nTo: <sip:alice@" + ipAddress + ":" + outPort + ">\r\nVia: SIP/2.0/UDP " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + ":" + sipSocket.getLocalPort() + ";branch=z9hG4bK-323032-" + generateCallId() + "\r\nMax-Forwards: 70\r\nContact: <sip:" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()+ ":" + sipSocket.getLocalPort() + ">\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n";
        sendData = method.getBytes();

        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, inetIpAddress, 5060);
        sipSocket.send(sendPacket);

        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
        sipSocket.receive(receivePacket);

        String response = new String(receivePacket.getData());
        System.out.println(ipAddress + "\n" + response);
        sipSocket.close();
    }

    //Generating unique callID
    public static String generateCallId(){
       Random r = new Random();
       long l1 = r.nextLong() * r.nextLong();
       long l2 = r.nextLong() * r.nextLong();
       return Long.toHexString(l1) + Long.toHexString(l2);

    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
        CheckSipUdp sip = new CheckSipUdp();
        sip.checkSipUdp(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));

    }
}
```